# How does making an XMLHttpRequest from a callback affect caching?

Tags: javascript, http, caching, xmlhttprequest, cache-control

When retrieving the following HTML in a browser, a Cache-control header is set by the browser for the XHTTP requests made in the main scope, but not for the request made from the timeout callback. This causes the second resource always to be loaded from cache unless cache is not present. Why does putting the request in a callback affect the cache headers like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var get = function (url) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
      }

      get("resource1.html");    // Cache-control set

      setTimeout(function () {
        get("resource2.html");  // Cache-control not set
      }, 10);

      get("resource3.html");    // Cache-control set

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(I've tested this on all the machines and browsers I have at hand and results are quite consistent. The one exception is that Firefox does seem to set a Cache-control header for the callback resource if the timeout is set to `0`, which other browsers still do not).

Answer (score -1):

Can't reproduce for now, but let's try to home in...

I tested with:

*app.js*

```
router.get(/resource./, function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=90');
  res.send('<hr/>');
});
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var get = function (url) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    get("resource1.html");    // Cache-control set

    setTimeout(function () {
        get("resource2.html");  // Cache-control not set
    }, 10);

    get("resource3.html");    // Cache-control set

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

They all get 200's ...

[image]

And cache-control

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: public, max-age=90
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
ETag: W/"5-mkFFtL4+3G6hWYdNAMJUPw"
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 16:09:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Also, the log:

1st time

```
Listening on port 3000
GET / 200 12.544 ms - 499
/resource1.html undefined
GET /resource1.html 200 1.389 ms - 5
/resource3.html undefined
GET /resource3.html 200 0.353 ms - 5
/resource2.html undefined
GET /resource2.html 200 0.233 ms - 5
```

2nd time

```
GET / 200 1.627 ms - 499
/resource1.html no-cache
GET /resource1.html 200 0.427 ms - 5
/resource3.html no-cache
GET /resource3.html 200 0.160 ms - 5
/resource2.html no-cache
GET /resource2.html 200 0.408 ms - 5
```

Comment: I'm asking about the `cache-control` headers being set in the browser's request, not the server's response. If you add `console.log(req.path, req.headers["cache-control"]);` to your `/resource./` handler, clear browser cache, and reload, you should see that the request for `resource2.html` has no `cache-control` header.

Comment: Apologies if the question was ambiguous. I've edited the text to clarify.

Comment: @IanMackinnon [updated] which browser are you using? Have you tried in `incognito` mode?